# Bitcoin-Qt command line control on Mac

Tags: bitcoin-core, mac, json-rpc, server

I'm trying to communicate with the new Bitcoin-Qt -server via a [command line](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_%28JSON-RPC%29#Controlling_Bitcoin) on Mac. I run ./Bitcoin-Qt -server, the application starts, but my terminal window is stuck on an empty line (no matter what I type in, there is no response). Only when I quit Bitcoin am I able to run any commands, but then I can't communicate with Bitcoin, because it is already off.

How do I start Bitcoin-Qt -server on Mac and control it through command line?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can start it from the command-line using:

```
open Bitcoin-Qt.app --args -server
```

I think the `--args` option to open is OSX 10.6 and later; if you are running an older OSX put `server=1` in your `~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/bitcoin.conf` file. In fact, to use the -server command you must set a `-rpcuser/-rpcpassword`, so I'd suggest creating a `bitcoin.conf` that contains:

```
server=1
rpcuser=yourname
rpcpassword=...something else
```

We don't ship a bitcoind for the Mac, but you can use curl (for example) to send commands to the running Bitcoin-Qt:

```
curl --user yourname --data-binary '{"id":"t0", "method": "getinfo", "params": [] }' http://127.0.0.1:8332/
```

The bitcoin source tree also contains python code that uses the free 'jsonrpc' library to communicate with a running Bitcoin-Qt (see contrib/bitrpc/).

Comment: Can you set the datadir also as shown here? http://sourceforge.net/projects/bitcoin/files/Bitcoin/testnet-in-a-box/  The example there shows it calling 'bitcoin'.  Still a little unclear on how to get testnet-in-a-box up and running on mac.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[bitcoind 0.5.x, starting with 0.5.6rc3](https://bitcointalk.org/?topic=87660) and [0.6.x starting with 0.6.3](http://luke.dashjr.org/programs/bitcoin/files/bitcoind/0.6.3/) include a deterministic Mac build. Unfortunately, bitcoind 0.7  does not build with the Mac OS X 10.5 toolchain (which is what I compiled for gitian), so until I [manage to make a LLVM-based cross-compiler](https://bitcointalk.org/?topic=83743) you'll have to stick to the new Debug window interface and JSON-RPC.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add rpcallowip:

```
open Bitcoin-Qt.app --args -server=1 -rpcuser=bitcoinrpc -rpcpassword=barfoo -rpcport=8332 -rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0
```