# cURL to Bitcoin-Qt on Mac fails

Tags: bitcoin-core, mac

I followed gavinadresen's answer at [Bitcoin-Qt command line control on Mac](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2570/bitcoin-qt-command-line-control-on-mac). When I enter the following in terminal, it works:

```
open Bitcoin-Qt.app --args -server
```

I've put in the following into my bitcoin.conf file:

```
rpcuser=yourname
rpcpassword=password
```

I entered the following in terminal:

```
curl --user yourname --data-binary '{"id":"t0", "method": "getinfo", "params": [] }' http://127.0.0.1:8332/
```

The above prompts me for the password and then it shows the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Error</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV='Content-Type' CONTENT='text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'>
</HEAD>
<BODY><H1>401 Unauthorized.</H1></BODY>
</HTML>
```

The above output doesn't look right.  Aren't I supposed to get data from Bitcoin?  How do I get the curl command to work?

Comment: Can you check if rpcssl=1 is set in the bitcoin.conf ? If so, bitcoin is excepting only HTTPS connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three things to check :

- Is there rpcssl=1 in your bitcoin.conf ? If so, set it to 0 or make HTTPS connections only
- Have you set rpcallowip=127.0.0.1 ?
- Try connect to http: //yourname:yourpassword@127.0.0.1:8332/ directly

And the fourth thing to check (as I saw your answer) :

- Check if you have correctly entered your username and password ;)

Comment: Please see my answer.  I tried entering http://yourname:yourpassword@127.0.0.1:8332/ into my browser and got {"result":null,"error":{"code":-32700,"message":"Parse error"},"id":null}.  How can I get this to work?

Comment: Just edited my answer so ;) Indeed rcpallowip and rcpssl are not required but they can help you configure correctly your install

Answer (score 0):

I had screwed up.  I entered the wrong yourname in

```
curl --user yourname --data-binary '{"id":"t0", "method": "getinfo", "params": [] }' http://127.0.0.1:8332/
```

as what I had entered for rpcuser= in my bitcoin.conf file.

When I entered the right yourname, the curl command responded with correct data from my bitcoin wallet.

I had tried entering the following into bitcoin.conf file but they were unnecessary and so I removed them:

```
rpcallowip=*
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcssl=1
```